# To extract specific string from txt file and copy the extracted string to json file in batch file

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, cmd

I have text file abc.txt with the contents as :

### abc.txt :

`{"nature":"calm","trees":"uprooted from the main area","name":"usdbuebcowecy821nkwh29y2bnso3ns389ye3wnsiwsn9usj","enrolled":"not yet"}`

I need to extract the string "usdbuebcowecy821nkwh29y2bnso3ns389ye3wnsiwsn9usj" associated with name from the abc.txt. The strings associated with name vary and are not static. Hence whatever the string is asociated with name has to be extracted and updated in a sample.json file .

### Sample.json :

```
 {
   "requisite":{
            "name": "usdbuebcowecy821nkwh29y2bnso3ns389ye3wnsiwsn9usj"
               },
             "land": {
                    "key": "890"
                   }
}
```

Sample.json file name key should be updated with the appropriate name extracted from abc.txt name field.

I tried below code snippet to extract the name field abc.txt file :

```
For /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%j in ('dir /b /s "C:\abc.txt" ^|findstr /I ""name":"') do echo "%%j" 
echo name is: %%j
```

However the loop doesnt search for the name string and Im stuck to proceed further. Im new to batch script. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why did you pick a scripting language that does not have a native method to read and write JSON?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q64985945.txt"
:: Read sourcefile to LINE
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET "line=%%a"
:: Change each { } and : to comma
SET "line=%line:{=,%"
SET "line=%line:}=,%"
SET "line=%line::=,%"
:: ensure NAME is not defined
SET "name="
:: process LINE
:: set NAME when the string `name` is detected, use that flag to set NAME to the value following.
:: Note that LINE will not contain {:}, so any of these values can be used as a flag to detect
:: `name` as the last value.
FOR %%a IN (%line%) DO IF DEFINED name (SET "name=%%~a"&GOTO done ) ELSE IF /i "%%~a"=="name" SET "name=:"
:noname
ECHO No name value found
GOTO :eof
:done
SET name

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances. The listing uses a setting that suits my system.

I used a file named `q64985945.txt` containing your data for my testing.

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

Unfortunately, you still keep the JSON text a er, mystery. The sample you've posted doesn't tell us a number of things - whether the first occurrence of `name` is the one you require, or whether there are other conditions that determine which particular value of `name` is to be selected. For instance, your original sample did not include nested brace-pairs. All significant in devising a solution...

Comment: for the sample.json, there is only one occurence of name in sample.json and the name key will be already having value. That value needs to be updated with new value obtained from abc.txt file's value . Here for example name's value in abc.txt is usdbuebcowecy821nkwh29y2bnso3ns389ye3wnsiwsn9usj and this value needs to be replaced in sample.json name field

Comment: @Magoo How can I the store multiple output of this `wmic cpu get loadpercentage, name, status` in multiple variables

Comment: @Thrainder : Best way is to create your own question and include your attempt to solve the problem (`wmic` output is tricky...) as your requirement is totally unrelated to the current question.

Comment: @Magoo yes that is a new question because I am not able to ask questions due to my reputation level and it was urgent for me. Yes I have already implemented this with my C# application. But still wants to know how we can assign the multiple output of a command (table structure) into multiple batch variables for example above mentioned command. How can I store the returned values of above command into variables like `%loadpercentage%, %name%, %status% ` and use them.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` command show file *names*. You want not to process the file name, but the file *contents*, isn't it? So you should give "abc.txt" as parameter of `findstr` command.

In the line you want *the sixth token* separated by *colon or comma*, right?

This works:

```
For /f "tokens=6 delims=:," %%j in ('findstr /I "name" abc.txt') do echo %%j
```

However, if the contents of file `abc.txt` is just one line (as you said in the question), then you don't even need the `findstr` command...

```
For /f "tokens=6 delims=:," %%j in (abc.txt) do echo %%j
```

---

This is another way to do it that extracts the values *of all variables* in the line:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Read a line from abc.txt
set /P "line=" < abc.txt
rem For example: {"nature":"calm","trees":"uprooted","name":"usd","enrolled":"not yet"}

rem Remove braces  ->  "nature":"calm","trees":"uprooted","name":"usd","enrolled":"not yet"
set "line=%line:~1,-1%"

rem Change ":" by =  ->  "nature=calm","trees=uprooted","name=usd","enrolled=not yet"
set "line=%line:":"==%"

rem Change "," by " & set "  ->  "nature=calm" & set "trees=uprooted" & set "name=usd" & set "enrolled=not yet"
rem and *execute* such a line inserting a SET command at beginning:
set %line:","=" & set "%

rem Now all variables have their values. For example:
echo {"name":"%name%"}
```

### New solution added

Your first request was to extract `name` field from `abc.txt` file. However, you have now *changed* the problem to *update* a line of `sample.json` file that in the original question have just one line.

Anyway, here it is a solution to your *new* problem:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get the value of "name": field in abc.txt file
for /f "tokens=6 delims=:," %%j in (abc.txt) do set "name=%%~j"

rem Get line number of "name": line minus one in sample.json file
for /F "delims=:" %%n in ('findstr /N "\"name\":" sample.json') do set /A "lines=%%n-1"

rem Process sample.json file and create sample.out
< sample.json (

   rem Copy first N lines
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%lines%) do set /P "line=" & echo !line!

   rem Read and update the "name": line as requested
   set /P "line="
   for /F "delims=:" %%a in ("!line!") do echo %%a: "%name%"

   rem Copy the rest of lines
   findstr "^"

) > sample.out

move /Y sample.out sample.json
```

Note that this code is prone to get errors because Batch files are not designed to process json files. If the program fails with your real data because a detail that is different from the posted data, please do not post here a request to fix the code!  **`:(`**

Comment: how to update the sample.json's name field with the value obtained from the abc.txt?

Comment: Just use file redirection: `echo {"name":"%name%"} > sample.json`

Comment: the sample.json file contains other key value fields, so file redirection of name field might not help as the name key will already be having value and the redirection just appends which shouldnt be. It should replace the existing value with new one

Comment: @Aacini : how about instead of `rem Change "," TO` use `FOR %%a IN (%line%) DO SET %%a`

Comment: @MYstery: If the sample .json file contains other values, we need a realistic sample

Comment: Can someone help me to store the multiple output of this `wmic cpu get loadpercentage, name, status` in multiple variable in batch file.

Comment: @Thrainder: sounds like you could post a new question about that. Show what you have tried to capture this data. Personally I think Windows batch files are awkward to use - do you have access to Python/PHP/etc in your Windows environment?

Comment: @halfer yes that is a new question because I am not able to ask questions due to my reputation level and it was urgent for me. Yes I have already implemented this with my C# application. But still wants to know how  we can assign the multiple output of a command (table structure) into multiple batch variables for example above mentioned command. How can I store the returned values of above command into variables like `%loadpercentage%, %name%, %status%`

Comment: @Thrainder: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage^,name^,status /value') do for /F %%b in ("%%a") do set "%%b"`

Answer (score 0):

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) has no support for JSON at all, so please use a tool like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) that does.

dot notation:

```
xidel -s sample.json -e "($json).requisite.name:=json-doc('abc.txt').name"
```

XQuery:

```
xidel -s sample.json -e "$json/map:put(.,'requisite',{'name':json-doc('abc.txt')/name})"
```

Output (to stdout) in both cases:

```
{
  "requisite": {
    "name": "usdbuebcowecy821nkwh29y2bnso3ns389ye3wnsiwsn9usj"
  },
  "land": {
    "key": "890"
  }
}
```

To update the input file simply use `--in-place`:

```
xidel -s --in-place sample.json -e "[...]"
```